Can I make a CMake compiler definition which expands to empty?
I want to do this...
#if IS_TESTING
#define MOCKABLE virtual
#else #define MOCKABLE
#endif

...but in CMake.
I have two executables defined in CMake, MAIN and TEST. I have tried doing this:
MAIN CMake file:

target_compile_definitions(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
PRIVATE
  MOCKABLE=
)

TEST CMake file:

target_compile_definitions(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME}
PRIVATE
  MOCKABLE=virtual
)

The TEST version works, but in MAIN, MOCKABLE expands to "" and so it won't compile. Is it possible to define it somehow so that MOCKABLE expands to nothing, like with a regular C or C++ macro?
In case it isn't obvious, my overall goal is for unit testing, so I can do something like this:
class A
{
   MOCKABLE void go() { ... }
}

...so that go() is virtual inside the testing executable, and non-virtual inside the main executable. The macro code at the beginning of this post works perfectly well, but I'd prefer to do it in CMake so that I don't have to worry about headers.

Which CMake version do you use? I have 3.22, and it emits error for target_compile_definitions call without PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE keyword. And with target_compile_definitions(foo PRIVATE MOCKABLE=) it actually defines the macro with empty value, so definition MOCKABLE void go() { ... } is valid.

The missing PRIVATE thing was just my C++ brain assuming it would be default. I've updated the original post.

I'm using 3.22 also. The weird thing is that when I create a new CMake 3.22 project and run it with MOCKABE=, it seems to work and MOCKABLE is empty. I don't know what's going on, but perhaps the TEST executable is shadowing the MAIN one somehow...
